# using usort on simpleXML that's been converted to an array

Tags: php, simplexml, usort

I have read a standard RSS feed into simpleXML and get the following after converting to an array:

```
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
    [guid] => https://www.zazzle.com/scissors_by_any_other_name_dreadful_pun_t_shirt-235586301981812394
    [pubDate] => Wed, 23 Aug 2017 13:41:08 GMT 
    [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
    [link] => https://www.zazzle.com/scissors_by_any_other_name_dreadful_pun_t_shirt-235586301981812394
    [author] => HightonRidley 
    [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
    [price] => $30.15 
    ) 
[1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
    [guid] => {not enough reputation points to show link} 
    [pubDate] => Sat, 19 Aug 2017 15:53:19 GMT 
    [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
    [link] => {not enough reputation points to show link} 
    [author] => HightonRidley 
    [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) 
    [price] => $15.65 ) 
)
```

This is the code used to create and display the above

```
$sortable = array();
foreach($product_grid->channel->item as $node) {
    $sortable[] = $node;
}
print_r($sortable);
```

To prove to myself it's working and accessible as intended I used this

```
foreach ($sortable as $rssitem) {
    echo "<br>" . $rssitem->pubDate;
}

echo "<br>".$sortable[0]->pubDate;
echo "<br>".$sortable[1]->pubDate;
```

and got this output

```
Wed, 23 Aug 2017 13:41:08 GMT
Sat, 19 Aug 2017 15:53:19 GMT
Wed, 23 Aug 2017 13:41:08 GMT
Sat, 19 Aug 2017 15:53:19 GMT
```

...but when I try to sort using usort, I get no output and Firefox console tells me I have a server error 500
Here's how I'm using usort

```
usort($sortable, function($a, $b)
{
    return strtotime($a->pubDate) > strtotime($b->pubDate);
});
```

I've checked various questions/answers on using usort here and as many other places as I can find online but to no avail.
Can someone please tell me how to reference the various elements of $sortable from within that anonymous function. I will be doing other sorts using other elements once I get this first one cracked.
Thanks!

Comment: That code works correctly. You must have an error somewhere else. What do the logs say? Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set("display_errors", "On");` at the top of the page to see what's wrong.

Comment: I have those already. I still get a blank screen. Actually, I have `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I see. Did you check the logs? You can see [here](https://3v4l.org/PPgC6) how it works in isolation.

Comment: Instead of using an anonymous function, I've since tried using named functions and that works. However, I need to use 8 different sorting options and so would rather use anonymous functions (pubdate, author, title, price -- low-to-high and high-to-low in each case).

Comment: Logs aren't helpful - I get a 500 178, whatever that means (the 178)

Comment: I had a look at your code, ishegg, but I think it's related to simpleXML and anonymous functions - your example doesn't shed light on that aspect.